# Header files. etc

Tags: c++, class, header

I defined a simple class. The definition is in the header file and the implmentation is in the cpp file:

HEADER:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y);

    int getX();
    int getY();

private:
    int x, y;
};

#endif
```

CPP

```
#include Point.h

Point::Point(int x=2, int y=2) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

int Point::getX() {
    return x;
}

int Point::getY() {
    return y;
}
```

This is not compiling and I am not sure why. Also, when I want to instantiate a point
somewhere else, say main.cpp, what do I #include at the top, just Point.h? If so, how does it know to look in Point.cpp?

Comment: in main, you do indeed just include point.h, point.cpp is a file that will be included automatically if you add it to your project.

Comment: I think you are missing the quotation marks, should be #include "Point.h"

Comment: `point.cpp` is a compilation unit, as `main.cpp` is. When you compile them, you create objects that both know how `point` is structured as they included the same header file. When you link your two objects you get your executable. You needn't the implementation to compile `main.h`, you need the declaration of the structures.

Comment: BTW, if you rename your parameters in the constructor, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax.  Also, prefer using an *initialization* list with the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes in your include

```
#include "Point.h"
```

In the file where you want to instantiate a Point you must include Point.h

Answer (score 8):

```
#include Point.h
```

You need quotes around `Point.h`.

```
Point::Point(int x=2, int y=2)
```

The default arguments should be in the declaration in the header file, not in the definition in the .cpp file (it will compile as-is, but won't do what you want).

On a stylistic note, it's usually a bad idea to name local variables or arguments the same as member variables:  doing so can easily lead to confusion.  You can also initialize member variables using an initializer list:

```
Point::Point(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { }
```

As your code is currently written, `x` and `y` are both constructed, then you assign to them.  Using an initializer list eliminates the assignment and just constructs them directly.  This doesn't matter for fundamental types like `int`, but it does matter for class types.

> This is not compiling and I am not sure why.

Usually the error message that the compiler issues is helpful.  If nothing else, if it isn't helpful to you, it's helpful to those of us trying to help.

> Also, when I want to instantiate a point somewhere else, say **main.cpp**, what do I `#include` at the top, just **Point.h**?

Yes.

> How does it know to look in Point.cpp?

Each .cpp file that you write gets compiled into a separate object file.  Once all the .cpp files are compiled into object files, the object files all get linked together into an excecutable (or a library).  The linker figures out where everything is defined.

Comment: @user620189 , if you found an answer helpful, please accept it by clicking on the check-mark outline next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the argument defaults in the header although without the error message I can't say if this is your problem. Also you should quote your include `#include "Point.h"`

Answer (score 1):

You defined default values for x and y in the implementation. This can't work. Think a bit how this is supposed to work if the clients of your class only see the header and hence have no idea that they could possibly call Point without default parameters?

The trick is that the implementation is compiled into your application, and calls get resolved using the declaration only (the stuff in the header). For each call, the compiler creates a symbol name and marks the call (for instance, when you call Point::getX, the compiler will insert call which looks like `call _getX@Point@`). The linker, which comes after the compiler will search for this function. If it's implemented, it will be found and the caller will get "redirected" to the `Point::getX()` source code.

[Edit] Oh and you need to write #include "Point.h".

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you're getting?

You just include the .h file:

```
#include "Point.h"
```

The linker resolves the references to code when it builds the executable.